# Prox identities in convex optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

\begin{aligned}
g_s(x) &= f(x) + \frac{1}{2s}\|x-x_0\|^2\\
\mbox{prox}_{t f}(y) &:= \arg\min_{x} \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x)\\
\mbox{prox}_{t g}(y) &:= \arg\min_{x} \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x) +  \frac{1}{2s}\|x-x_0\|^2\\
\end{aligned}

$f(x) $ is convex. I want to find the formula for $\mbox{prox}_{t g}$ in terms of $\mbox{prox}_{t f}$.

I tried to write $\mbox{prox}_{t g}$ interm of expressions with $\| x - (y+x_0) \|^2 $ but the math does not work because I have $\frac{1}{2t}$ related  to $\|x-y\|^2$ and $\frac{1}{2s}$ related to $\|x-x_0\|^2$. I know that free terms with only $y$  and $x_0$ should not change the optimization result but still I have the wrong coefficient for $x^Tx$ and therefore could not make progress.

Next I took the gradient of both terms and compare to zero but could not get any insight from this.

Comment: Use subdifferential characterization of prox + some algebra

Comment: What is subdifferential characterization ?

Comment: See answer below. Lemme know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space on which your variables live, for example euclidean $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\partial g : \mathcal H \to 2^{\mathcal H}$ be the *subdifferential* of $g$ defined for any $x \in \mathcal H$ by
$$
\partial g(x) := \{v \in \mathcal H \mid f(z) \ge f(x) + \langle v,z-x\rangle\,\forall z \in \mathcal H\}.
$$

Recall that $\partial g(x)$ is called the *subgradient* of $g$ at $x$. By the *subgradient characterization* of prox-operators (see derivation in appendix further below), one has $p = \mathrm{prox}_{tg}(y)$ iff $y-p \in t\partial g(p)$. Now, because $g(x) \equiv f(x) +  \|x-x_0\|^2/(2s)$, we know from elementary properties of subdifferentials that $\partial g(x) \equiv \partial f(x) + (x-x_0)/s$. Thus,
$$
\begin{split}
p = \mathrm{prox}_{tg}(y) &\iff y-p \in t\partial f(p) + t(p-x_0)/s\\
&\iff (y+tx_0/s) - (1+t/s)p \in t\partial f(p)\\
& \iff (y+tx_0/s)/\alpha - p \in (t/\alpha)\partial f(p),\text{ where }\alpha := 1+t/s\\
& \iff p = \mbox{prox}_{(t/\alpha)f}(s(y)),
\end{split}
$$
where $s(y) := (y+tx_0/s)/\alpha$, an affine transformation. Thus, we have shown that
$$
\mbox{prox}_{tg}(y) = \mbox{prox}_{(t/\alpha)f}(s(y)).
$$

---

### Appendix: Subgradient characterization of prox-operators

**Claim 1.** If $h:\mathcal H \to (-\infty,\infty]$ is a function (convex or not), then $x \in \arg\min h$ iff $0 \in \partial h(x)$.

**Proof.** Indeed,
$$
\begin{split}
x \in \arg\min h &\iff h(z) \ge h(x) \,\forall z \in\mathcal H\\
& \iff h(z) \ge h(x) + \langle 0,z-x\rangle\,\forall z \in \mathcal H\\
& \iff 0 \in \partial h(x).
\end{split}
$$

**Claim 2:** $p = \mathrm{prox}_{tg}(y)$ iff $y-p \in t\partial g(p)$.

**Proof.** Indeed, applying **Claim 1** with $h := g + \|\cdot - y\|^2/(2t)$, we have $p=\mbox{prox}_{tg}(y)$ iff $p \in \arg\min h$ iff $0 \in \partial h(p) = \partial g(p) + (p-y)/t$ iff $y-p \in t \partial g(p)$. $\quad\quad\quad\Box$

Comment: Could you please explain how did you get to $p = \mathrm{prox}_{tg}(y)$ iff $y-p \in t\partial g(p)$

Comment: I've added an explanation